# Put a value in a text input into a Table Row (TR)

Tags: jquery

This code selects one unique row (TR) of a table :

```
var tr = $('table#table_info_etudiant tr:has(td:contains("'+stageId+'"))');
```

This Tr contains two inputs (text).

I would like to put a value in the first input of this tr (the class of this tr is "text_changer_date_debut")

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the inputs, select the first with `:first` or `first()`, and use `val()` to set the value ?

```
tr.find('input:first').val('some new value')
```

Comment: thank you, it works great.  :first will be replace by what for the second one ?

Comment: `tr.find('input:last')` if there are only two, or `tr.find('input:eq(1)')` if there are more (eq is zero based)